# Can I color the same string in one Excel file or CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, the first and third columns are compared, and if they are the same character string, they are colored.
Repeat this line by line.

I want to know how to do this using python.
It would be nice if you could give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how this can done in an excel file. The `openpyxl` or `xlswriter` module could be an good starting point -google for *python excel module* for more).

But for a csv file, I am sorry the the only way is to print it and then use coloured pencils on the printed paper. A CSV file is a plain **text** file